# how to test configuration classes that rely on the @ConfigurationProperties annotation?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to how to test configuration classes that rely on the @ConfigurationProperties annotation to make sure that my configuration data is loaded and bound correctly to their corresponding fields.

Here is class annotioned by @ConfigurationProperties

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "config")
public class SomeConfig {

    private HashMap<String,String> smsTypeMap;

    public HashMap<String, String> getSmsTypeMap() {
        return smsTypeMap;
    }

    public void setSmsTypeMap(HashMap<String, String> smsTypeMap) {
        this.smsTypeMap = smsTypeMap;
    }
}
```

Here is application.yml:

```
config:
  smsTypeMap:
    a: aliSmsPlateform
    b: yzxSmsPlateform
    c: mlrtSmsPlateform
```

I want to test it by unit test.
thanks

UPDATE：
I try :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = SomeConfig.class)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application.yml")
public class SomeConfigTest {
    @Autowired
    private SomeConfig someConfig;

    @Test
    public void getSmsTypeMap() {
        //Here someConfig.getSmsTypeMap() return null...
        Assert.assertNotNull(someConfig.getSmsTypeMap());
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want to test Spring Boot?

Comment: what have you try that does not work?

Comment: @M.Deinum yes..

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai someConfig.getSmsTypeMap() return null

Comment: For autowiring to work you need an application context so I think you should use the `@SpringBootTest` annotation as well then have the properties in an `application-test.properties` under test src/..

Comment: So you don't trust the tests that Spring Boot itself does to check the correct functioning of `@ConfigurationProperties`? You shouldn't test it, write an integration test to test the functionality of your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `src/test/resources/config/application.yml` add

```
config:
  smsTypeMap:
    a: 'aliSmsPlateform'
    b: 'yzxSmsPlateform'
    c: 'mlrtSmsPlateform'
```

then you can have these classes

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties({SomeConfig.class})
public class MySpringBootApp {
}


@SpringBootTest(classes = MySpringBootApp.class)
public class PropertiesTest {

    @Autowired
    private SomeConfig properties;

    @Test
    public void assertThatUserMustExistToResetPassword() {

        assertThat(properties).isNotNull();
        assertThat(properties.getSmsTypeMap().get("a")).isEqualTo("aliSmsPlateform");
        assertThat(properties.getSmsTypeMap().get("b")).isEqualTo("yzxSmsPlateform");
        assertThat(properties.getSmsTypeMap().get("c")).isEqualTo("mlrtSmsPlateform");
    }
}
```